# @font-face does not work in IE8, works in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My font does not appear in **IE8**, but it works in **IE9**.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ziggurat-HTF-Black';
  src: url('fonts/ziggurat-htf-black.eot');
  src: url('fonts/ziggurat-htf-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/ziggurat-htf-black.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/ziggurat-htf-black.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/ziggurat-htf-black.svg#ziggurat-htf-black') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Note:** I took this from another posted solution on stack overflow, so seriously it's not a duplicate of another question.

Comment: live site or local? and what type of server? iis?

Comment: Semi-live wordpress site...currently in "maintenance mode". Apache.

Comment: Would be easier to troubleshoot if there was a live link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine, I would look at server configuration or the font file itself. Did you use a conversion tool? Try converting the font again.

Check to see if you can access the EOT file directly (should be fine if it works in IE9).

Are there any CSS classes targeting IE8? Check to see if they are changing the font family.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure what's wrong here, but my suggestion would be to use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) to generate the necessary cross-browser compatible CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my Ziggurat-Black to work by following the advice in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169311/564879

*"The most common reason fonts don't load in IE is because the font name table was coded wrong by the font author. That is definitely the case with Josefin. The Family Name + the Style Name must = The Full Name. Josephine fails this. FYI - fontsquirrel.com automatically corrects these problems in their webfonts."*

Comment: Good to know because I've used that font before.

Comment: As an FYI: fontsquirrel.com unfortunately blocks processing Ziggurat, so I ultimately had to edit the metadata and re-export the font from Font Forge to fix this one.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127439/339852):

> Older version of Internet Explorer supports [*Embedded OpenType (EOT)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127439/339852) files before `@font-face` was formalized in CSS3.

Comment: Hm are you pointing out licensing or .eot? Because I am linking .eot in the source url above?